# How to change notification sound by code in android?

Tags: android, notifications

Anyone knows how to change notification sound by code in android.
I have managed to set the default ringtone, but cant find a way to set the notification tone...

I would be thankful for any response, as code example, psudo code or just name of a which part of the sdk i need to use...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control this on a per-`Notification` basis via the [sound field on `Notification`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#sound). Note that I haven't tried this personally, but it's what the docs say.

Comment: so, notifications does not automatically play the default notification tone? I would have to specify it when i create the notification ?

Comment: By overall default, notifications play no tone. You can use the defaults field on a Notification to indicate which defaults should be used (e.g., DEFAULT_SOUND). Or, you can override the tone on a per-Notification basis. It is unclear if there is a way to set the default notification tone via code.

Answer (score 10):

here it is

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,      uriObjectofYourAudioFile);
```

Answer (score 4):

This might be helpful

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.packagename.org/raw/alert");
```