# Notification sound not playing

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked many times, but I'm still having issues getting it working.

In my application, I create a notification to prompt the user of some event and I'd like to play a sound that has been packaged as a raw resource within the application.

I create my notification instance:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(
        R.drawable.some_image,
        "some meaningful name",
        System.currentTimeMillis() );

notification.setLatestEventInfo(...)
```

Then set some attributes on that notification:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse( "android.resource://com.my.package/" + R.raw.some_mp3_file );
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
```

Finally I invoke the NotificationManager to display the notification:

```
notificationManager.notify( 1, notification );
```

The notification does shows up, but the sound doesn't play.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a <uses-permission> I'm missing?  I can't see anything that I've done differently from anyone else that seems to have gotten it working.

For what it's worth, I'm testing directly on a Nexus 7.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to look at below code. may help you out to solve your problems.

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        int icon = R.drawable.update;
        CharSequence tickerText = "assignments";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification assignmentNotification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
       **For sound** assignmentNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        long[] vibrate = {0,100,200,300};
       **For vibrate** assignmentNotification.vibrate = vibrate;
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "check assignments";
        CharSequence contentText = "chek ur app for assignments ";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ViewAssignmentnotificationActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,0);
        assignmentNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
       ** final int id = 2;
```

Comment: thank you but this isn't quite what i was asking for.  i've got a specific sound bundled as a raw resource in my application that i want to play in conjunction with my notifications - not the default sound/ringtone as your sample code shows.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770772/how-to-change-notification-sound-by-code-in-android); It tells you that you have to explicitly specify notification.sound to play that tone;

Comment: look at the first line of the second block of code in my original post - that's exactly what i've done, is it not?

Comment: I accept; but try the default URI in the link i've posted; we mi8 narrow the problem that way

Comment: no joy.  i first invoked `RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri()`, passing in the same Uri from my original post as the last parameter.  then i set did `notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;`... the notification shows up, but the sound doesn't play.

Comment: Are you developing your app on 4.0 platform and checking it on ICS or above?

Comment: compiled against 3.2 (api 13), running on 4.1.1 (api 16).  i have a lingering feeling that it's somewhat related to this, but haven't really thought it through...

Comment: pls try your code in Gingerbread and say; coz i've downloaded a sample app, which works well in GingerBread but not giving any sound in ICS