# c# android GCM notification disable sound

Tags: c#, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to remove sound notification upon receiving gcm notification on android phone. I set `data.sound=0` in my code but nothing. Android plays sound even app is closed!
Is there any way to achieve my target?
Thank you.

```
public void SendNotification(string deviceId, string message, int badgeCount) 
{
    string GoogleAppID = "....";
    var SENDER_ID = ".....";

    WebRequest webRequest;
    webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
    webRequest.Method = "post";
    webRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
    webRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));
    webRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

    string postData = string.Format("collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=0&data.message={0} &data.time={1} &data.badge={3} &data.sound={4}&registration_id={2}", message, DateTime.UtcNow, regID, badgeCount, "default");

    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
    {
        String sResponseFromServer = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        webResponse.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you write Android apps in C#?

Comment: VS .NET Pro 2013, it is a WFA application

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Notification.Builder` with public method `setDefaults`.

As mentioned in [setDefaults](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDefaults(int)),

> `Notification.Builder setDefaults (int defaults)`
>
> Set which notification properties will be inherited from system defaults.

Please note that value should be `DEFAULT_SOUND` to use the default notification sound.

Solutions given and a couple of comments in this SO post - [How to change notification sound by code in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770772/how-to-change-notification-sound-by-code-in-android) hope helps you understand better.