# Android GCM notification using sound

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have a php code that send to GCM information to notification to user, this code send ok and I receive in my android device, but the sound and badge don't worked. I don't know why.

On array `$msg` only a field 'message work', other fields don't work.

How can I fix this? This is my code:

```
<?php

//Checking http request we are using post here 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

//Getting api key 
$api_key = $_POST['apikey'];    

//Getting registration token we have to make it as array 
$reg_token = array($_POST['regtoken']);

//Getting the message 
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Creating a message array 
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => $message,
    'title'     => 'Message from Simplified Coding',
    'subtitle'  => 'Android Push Notification using GCM Demo',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    "sound"=> "default",
    "badge"=> "2",
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);

//Creating a new array fileds and adding the msg array and registration token array here 
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $reg_token,
    'data'          => $msg
);

//Adding the api key in one more array header 
$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . $api_key,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
); 

//Using curl to perform http request 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

//Getting the result 
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

//Decoding json from result 
$res = json_decode($result);


//Getting value from success 
$flag = $res->success;

//if success is 1 means message is sent 
if($flag == 1){
    //Redirecting back to our form with a request success 
    header('Location: index.php?success');
}else{
    //Redirecting back to our form with a request failure 
    header('Location: index.php?failure');
}
}
```

Comment: Default sound should work, as it is whatever the device has set as the default notification sound. As for the badge that is a feature that is available on iOS devices not Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have existing sound files.

As mentioned in [Notification payload support](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support), `sound` parameter indicates a sound to play when the device receives the notification.

> Android sound files must reside in `/res/raw/`, while iOS sound files can be in the main bundle of the client app or in the Library/Sounds folder of the app’s data container.

Please also note that using [DEFAULT_SOUND](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_SOUND) will ignore any given sound.

For additional information, please check solution given in this SO post - [How to change notification sound by code in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770772/how-to-change-notification-sound-by-code-in-android). Hope it helps.